# How can I change the sort order of the Default blog page in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: blog, sorting

How can I change the sort order of the Default blog page in SharePoint 2010? Currently the default sort order is by Published date. I would like to change it to where it sorts by Category (which is a protected field) then by Published date. My problem is when I go to change the sort order Category is not in the drop-down list. So I guess my real question is how can I get Category to show up in sort order drop-down list so I can select it? Any guidance on this will be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I think the Category column is set as multi-valued by default in the Blog template, are you able to set it to single-valued? Multi-valued columns can't be sorted in a list.

Comment: Category is a protected field (it was created by SharePoint). So where can I change it to a single value?

Comment: If you look for the list that stores in the Posts in View All Site Content, then go to List Settings for that list, then find the Categories field, you should be able to change it to Single Value there.

Comment: Okay--I tried your suggestion and unfortunately the Category field cannot be changed. I even went into SharePoint Designer and tried to do it there and I got a message stating that sealed fields cannot be changed. Have you been able to change it????

Comment: Never tried. What you could do, I guess, is create a new field for Categories, set it as a lookup that points to the Categories list, and set it to single valued. I'm not certain how this will effect the post authoring experience though (ie: not sure if you can set the category in the way you normally do).

Comment: Okay--I tried creating another field (Group) and made it a single value lookup field. The field works fine and I can sort in the Posts view. BUT I cannot sort on the main/defualt blog view which is the summary view. For some reason it will not recognize my Group field and the Categories list does not recognize the Group field either. So now I'm in a real pickle. If I can change the Summary view and the Categories list to recognize the Group field I'll be good to go. Do you know (or does anyone know) how I can get to those areas????

Comment: The Categories list just works independently of the Group column in the Posts list (I think), so you should be able to add new Categories and be able to select them in the Group lookup field. Is the summary view on the homepage? You might need to edit that webpart in situ on the page then set the sort order by editing the view in the Web Part Properties.

Comment: When a View is chosen in Web Part Properties, the view is 'copied' and used for the web part instance. If you update the View in the List itself, it won't update web parts that use it until you go into the web part properties and select the view again.

Answer (score 1):

Since blogs in SharePoint are sequenced in chronological order of their posting, to change the order requires time travel.  Actually, you can edit the time field in the publishing properties for the post. Simply apply new publishing times to all of the posts in the order that you want them to appear.

To perform this task, go to the Post list (Click the Manage Post List on the Blog Home Page), select the individual post to edit and change the Published time (I wish it was that easy to fool time in the real world).

Good luck -- Jerry

Comment: Hmmm! I tried your suggestion and it kinda sorta works. Yes the publish date changes, but the time does not. For example: OLD DATE= 02/14/12 OLD TIME= 4:29 PM NEW DATE= 03/26/12 NEW TIME= 4:29 PM (even though I did it at 11:01 AM).

Answer (score 1):

Click edit page on the blog home page. 
This should then allow you to edit the posts webpart. 
In the web part under List Views click edit view. 
Sort by ascending hit ok and save.